# Cannot install Guest Additions in Ubuntu 12.10 Alpha 2

Tags: installation, virtualbox, 12.10

i cannot install guest additions in Ubuntu 12.10 Alpha 2. Autorun Prompt will not successfully launch. Running in Terminal, after uncompressing Additions Terminal will suddenly close. I tried to run something in ADDITIONS ISO, it works but I can't adjust HD Resolutions like 1920X1080 and self-adjusted resolution.(SELF-ADJUSTED RESOLUTION means AUTO RESIZE GUEST DISPLAY one. Help!

The next question, WILL it happen again in 12.10 Daily Build and 12.10 Alpha 3 that just have released today or yesterday???